# Error code: attempt to call a nil value [LUA]

Tags: lua

after pressing the "button2" works correctly but after a while lua turns off
error: [Lua] Error in “LUA”: attempt to call a nil value

```
local webHookURL = Menu.TextBox("Webhook", "Webhook URL", 148, "", "Enter your webhook URL")
local message = ("Hello!")

local function hook(msg)
    Http.PostAsync(string.format("%s",webHookURL:GetString()),
    string.format("content=%s",msg))
    Cheat.AddNotify("neverlose.cc", "Shared! Well done!")
end


button2:RegisterCallback(function()
        hook(message)   
end)
```

Comment: is it for roblox?

Answer (score 0):

The error message doesn't indicate at which line the calling is happening?
A trivial workaround is to test it before:

```
if type(var_that_will_be_called) == "function" then
   var_that_will_be_called ()
end
```

But that doesn't really solve the problem, just avoid the error...